# Add a field to the ModelAdmin Form

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-forms

I want to give users the possibility to create multiple events at once. Therefore I would like to add a field to the admin-add-page where a number of repetitions can be specified. Then I want to override the save function and create multiple events (based on the input). I started writing some code but the admin add page does not update at all. I will show you the code below:

In admins.py:

```
class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = EventForm
admin.site.register(Event, EventAdmin)
```

In forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.db import models
from calendar_app.models import Event
class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100) # just for testing purpose
    class Meta:
        model = Event

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EventForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if not kwargs.has_key('instance'):
            self.fields['name'] = forms.CharField(label='Name')
            self.base_fields['name'] = forms.CharField(label='Name') 

    def save(self, commit=True):
        model = super(EventForm, self).save(commit=False)
        # Save all the fields...
        if commit:
            model.save()
        return model
```

But the "name" field is not showing up when I add an event. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Woha I used models.CharField instead of forms.CharField. Hours wasted...

Comment: I'd suggest adding your solution as an answer and closing this question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used models.CharField instead of forms.CharField. See comments.